# What is default fiddler gzip configuration?

Tags: tomcat, gzip, fiddler

I enable gzip compression for my tomcat by following setting:

`compressableMimeType="text/html, text/xml, text/css, text/plain, application/json, application/javascript, application/x-javascript, application/xml"`

but i cannot get the page size as low as when I use Fiddler's Transformer: Tomcat's output is 2.3MB vs Fiddler's is 2.0MB.

What is [Fiddler's](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) default gzip configuration?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Fiddler uses the Xceed Streaming Compression library for compression; the default compression level is "highest" which is probably equivalent to the "9" setting in other GZIP implementations.

[http://doc.xceedsoft.com/products/XceedWfWorkflow/Xceed.Compression.Formats~Xceed.Compression.Formats.GZipCompressedStream~_ctor(Stream).html](http://doc.xceedsoft.com/products/XceedWfWorkflow/Xceed.Compression.Formats~Xceed.Compression.Formats.GZipCompressedStream~_ctor%28Stream%29.html)

Note that you can get even higher compression ratios using [ZopFli](http://code.google.com/p/zopfli/).